# Why FB direct message and camera button has different location between ios and android?

Tags: buttons, facebook

Why FB direct message and camera button has different location between ios and android?

Android: DM is upper
iOS: Camera is upper

Anyone knows why is the button is location switching?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, unless there are any Facebook employees on this board, you are only likely to get opinions rather than facts for this question. We can hazard a guess that Facebook has studied the different use habits for users on the platforms and adapted accordingly but, ultimately, we'll never really know for sure without information directly from Facebook.

Comment: To clarify, those are not direct messages. That's direct photo/video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can really tell unless they're working for Facebook specifically on that team, but for me, it looks like a classic case of “it depends in which A/B testing bucket you've landed” unless it's consistent across different Android and iOS devices.